# C# HttpWebRequest returns blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have been reading through innumerable related questions to my problem but none of them have resolved my issue.  I am making a HttpWebRequest in c# in which I post data and then read the response except that the response always returns as blank.  I have tried changing `request.contentType`, encoding the data in various formats from unencoded, ASCII, & UTF8.  No matter what I do my response is blank.  Also as a side note, my request is going through layer 7.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
var postData = "\"device\"=\"9856\"";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
//request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", b64);
request.Headers.Add("reqtime", hmacTS);
request.Headers.Add("appkey", APP_KEY1);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

try
{
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        updateWindow(this, "Results: " + result);
        updateWindow(this, "Type: " + response.ContentType);
        updateWindow(this, "Content Length: " + response.ContentLength);
    }
}
catch (WebException a)
{
    updateWindow(this, "ERROR: " + a);
}
```

My response show as:

```
Results:  
Type: application/octet-stream
Content Length: 0
```

Just to update everyone, I finally got to the root of the problem.  The service provider had to restart their server because the database connection had went out.  After about a week of fighting with this code I guess they decided to check finally for me.....  Thanks to all who tried to help!

Comment: Have you tried using something like Fiddler to actually **see** what you're sending and receiving over the wire?

Comment: Yes I have been using fiddler and the body appears to be correct.  Also fiddler doesn't show any exceptions to the transaction.

Comment: I see no response body in fiddler.  Apparently I get nothing in return.. Content-Length: 0, Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: Do you have any helpful suggestions Mr. Wills?

Comment: Do you get empty responses when you try the same POST from Postman? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I have never used Postman, I must admit I am not a programmer by trade.  I am self taught over the last year or so.  I will see what I can figure out with Postman.

Comment: @wjwills.  I have changed my postdata to json format and specified content.type as json.  I also tried using formatting as utf8 and formatting my text appropriately. Still the same results.  I assume I am not formatting the text as the server intends to see it or something like that.

Comment: Please update your question with the current code, so we are all talking about the same thing... Also, what website / service are you posting the data to? Do they specify whether to post as json or other format?

Comment: The web service is one that we use at our company.  It is a java application and i expect to receive a long set of json values in return. I am trying to get some info from them as to what they except but they only deal with java and aren't much help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool GetResponseForJson( string url, out object jsonObject )
{
  bool result;

  try {

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( url );
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = ( HttpWebResponse )webRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() );
    jsonObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject( sr.ReadToEnd() );
    result = true;
  }
  catch {

    jsonObject = null;
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
```

That's a method I use for getting response objects from a url, you can change webRequest.Method to GET etcetera.

Comment: Thank you for the sugguestion.  Your code is pretty much the same as mine with the exception of the Json deserialization.  I tried this suggestion but my response is still blank.

Comment: @Konan so in your case, sr.ReadToEnd() returns an empty string?

Comment: @Konan I don't believe that would actually be an issue from your end then

Answer (score 0):

First check respone HTTP code. Also you are using authorization. Check if Authorization header value is correct. In case you are using bearer token authorization, you need to put "bearer" before actual token in header.

Comment: I am using authorization and my authorization header value is correct.  If I were getting an exception through layer 7 wouldn't it show some form of error?

Comment: It depends on the backend implementation. Correct way is to return status via HTTP code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **Accept** header to the request:

```
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```

This worked for me.